# How to replace characters based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
new = ['|<', '@', '1', '3', '7', '0', '8', '\/']
old = ['K', 'A', 'L', 'E', 'T', 'O', 'B', 'V']
ask_user = input("Type a sentence: ")

def ask_replace_letters():
    ask_user = input("Do you want to replace letters? ").upper()
    if ask_user == "YES":
        ask_user1 = input("What letters do you want to replace? ").upper()
        for letter in ask_user1:
            if letter not in old:
                print("This program cannot replace the letter(s): ", letter)
                print(replace_letters())

    elif ask_user == "NO":
        print(replace_phrases())

    else:
        print("Please enter yes or no.")

def replace_letters():
    result = ask_user
    for i in range(len(old)):
        result = result.replace(old[i], new[i])
    return result

ask_replace_letters()
```

When I run the code I get:

```
Type a sentence: BYE
Do you want to replace letters? yes
What letters do you want to replace? BYW 
This program cannot replace the letter(s):  Y
8Y3
This program cannot replace the letter(s):  W
8Y3
```

What I want:

```
Type a sentence: BYE
Do you want to replace letters? YES
What letters do you want to replace? BYW
This program cannot replace the letter(s):  YW
8YE
```

Is there a way to go around this? Basically I want the function to take the character the user input, check if it's in the list, change it, and state the ones that couldn't be changed. Sorry I'm still somewhat new to Python.

Comment: Please don't remove code from your posts, it makes your question unintelligible. If you do not want your account to be associated with this question, you can disassociate yourself from this post. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `str.translate` here for quick and efficient replacement.

First, build a dictionary of mappings - `<old : new>`, this becomes a global variable.

```
trans_dict = dict(zip(old, new))
```

Next, define a function to perform the replacement. The function takes your input string, and a replacement pattern. Use `set` operations to segregate valid characters from the invalid ones.

Perform a translation operation on all valid characters.

```
def replace(string, repl):
    repl = set(repl)
    # find invalid characters
    invalid = repl - trans_dict.keys()
    # find valid characters in `repl` - replacement is performed on these chars only
    valid = repl - invalid

    # display invalid characters to stdout
    print('Cannot replace {}'.format(''.join(invalid)))

    # translate/map string using the `trans_dict` mapping
    return string.translate(
        str.maketrans({k : trans_dict[k] for k in trans_dict.keys() & valid}
    ))
```

```
In [222]: replace('BYE', 'BYW')
Cannot replace YW
Out[222]: '8YE'
```

This code will run on python3.x only.

Comment: Interesting. Never really thought of using str.translate but it makes sense this way.

Comment: @user3000345 The benefit of translate is that it is optimised, and _fast_ (linear time). This entire algorithm is linear (as opposed to the others which are quadratic at best).

Answer (score 0):

I think tis should work (it did for me):

```
new = ['|<', '@', '1', '3', '7', '0', '8', '\/']
old = ['K', 'A', 'L', 'E', 'T', 'O', 'B', 'V']
ask_user = input("Type a sentence: ")

def ask_replace_letters():
    ask_user2=input("Do you want to replace letters? ").upper()#different name for variable
    if ask_user2== "YES":
        ask_user1 = input("What letters do you want to replace? ").upper()
        letters=[]#letters to replace
        for letter in ask_user1:
            if letter not in old:
                print("This program cannot replace the letter: ", letter)#may be repeated
            else:
                letters+=letter#add letter to letters to replace
        print(replace_letters(letters))#replace them

    elif ask_user2 == "NO":
        print(replace_letters())

    else:
        print("Please enter yes or no.")

def replace_letters(letters=[]):#input for which chars to replace, rather than all
    result = ask_user.upper()#so it will match
    for i in letters:#for each to replace
        pos=old.index(i)#get pos in old/new lists
        result = result.replace(old[pos], new[pos])#replace
    return result.lower()#lower, since we have done upper

ask_replace_letters()
```

This will, however, make it all lower. Remove the last line of replace letters to make it all upper.

Comment: Per-character is always going to be slow and inefficient. Also, you may want to _explain_ what your code is doing instead of just dumping it into an answer.

Comment: have added commentation

Answer (score 0):

Following your kind of output, I suggest the following change in one of your if clauses:

```
if ask_user == "YES":
    ask_user1 = input("What letters do you want to replace? ").upper()
    unreplacedLetters = ''.join([letter for letter in ask_user1 if letter not in old])
    print("This program cannot replace the letter(s): ", unreplacedLetters)
    print(replace_letters())
```

I created the 'unreplacedLetters' string, which uses the function join to put all letters that are not in old together without any space. Also, I declared the whole list to be joined as a list comprehension, to make the code concise. I tried here and it worked.

Comment: This performs an in check on a list, which is O(n).

Comment: This looks super efficient! Thank you.

Comment: @user3000345 It is anything _but_ efficient.

Comment: I wanted to give a concise answer, and wasn't familiar with the str.translate function (see answer below). Thanks for the comment, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input("Enter the sentence")
x1 = x.replace('a','4').replace('e','3').replace('i','1').replace('o','0').replace('u','5')
print(x1)
```

input:

```
Javascript is cool
```

output:

```
j4v4scr1pt 1s s0 c00l
```